# Unable to get window width

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, window

I've got a WPF window, and I'm trying to get the `Width` property. No matter where I try to present the code, it always returns as `NaN`.  I have looked up on the internet and read that I should actually be using `ActualWidth` instead, but this returns 0 no matter what.

How can I get rid of the lag and get an actual value for my window's width?

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Name="TableWindow" x:Class="QueryBuilder.DatabaseTable"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        WindowStyle="None" Background="Transparent" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" ResizeMode="CanResize">
    <Grid>
        <DockPanel>
            <StackPanel Name="titleBar" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="28" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Orientation="Horizontal" Background="AliceBlue">
                <Button x:Name="btnClose" Margin="0,0,5,0" Click="btnClose_Click">
                </Button>
                <Button>
                </Button>
                <Button>
                </Button>
                <Button x:Name="btnAll">ALL</Button>
                <Label Name="lblTableName" FontSize="15" Margin="50,0,0,0"></Label>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Name="spFields">
            </StackPanel>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**XAML.cs:**

```
public DatabaseTableWindow(string tableName, DataTable fields, string primaryKey)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.tableName = tableName;
            this.fields = fields;
            this.primaryKey = primaryKey;
            lblTableName.Content = tableName;
            double x = this.ActualWidth;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we've been chatting in the WPF room regarding this question, this was a compounded problem to seemingly easy thing.

If we set width / height on mdiChild, we end up losing resize functionality. so I've posted a gist with the fix that seems to have solved this issue as per our [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/5962571#5962571)

---

so to get the size bound, I used normal bindings (this copy paste from my test project):

```
<Window x:Class="TestApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:MDI="clr-namespace:WPF.MDI;assembly=WPF.MDI" xmlns:TestApplication="clr-namespace:TestApplication"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" Title="MainWindow">
    <MDI:MdiContainer Name="mainContainer">
        <MDI:MdiChild x:Name="mdiChild" MaximizeBox="False" MinimizeBox="False" Resizable="True" ShowIcon="False" Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=childElement}" Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=childElement}">
            <TestApplication:DatabaseTable x:Name="childElement"/>
        </MDI:MdiChild>
    </MDI:MdiContainer>
</Window>
```

this solves the primary width & height issue.

---

This piece of code needs to replace the [MdiChild.cs Changeset 81799](http://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/81799#666802) resize handler source in WPF.MDI library (you can replace the existing relevant code in there with this):

```
/// <summary>
/// Handles the DragDelta event of the ResizeLeft control.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
/// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
private void ResizeLeft_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    if (ActualWidth - e.HorizontalChange < MinWidth)
        return;

    double newLeft = e.HorizontalChange;

    if (Position.X + newLeft < 0)
        newLeft = 0 - Position.X;

    Width = ActualWidth - newLeft;
    Position = new Point(Position.X + newLeft, Position.Y);

    if (sender != null)
        Container.InvalidateSize();
}

/// <summary>
/// Handles the DragDelta event of the ResizeTop control.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
/// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
private void ResizeTop_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    if (ActualHeight - e.VerticalChange < MinHeight)
        return;

    double newTop = e.VerticalChange;

    if (Position.Y + newTop < 0)
        newTop = 0 - Position.Y;

    Height = ActualHeight - newTop;
    Position = new Point(Position.X, Position.Y + newTop);

    if (sender != null)
        Container.InvalidateSize();
}

/// <summary>
/// Handles the DragDelta event of the ResizeRight control.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
/// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
private void ResizeRight_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    if (ActualWidth + e.HorizontalChange < MinWidth)
        return;

    Width = ActualWidth + e.HorizontalChange;

    if (sender != null)
        Container.InvalidateSize();
}

/// <summary>
/// Handles the DragDelta event of the ResizeBottom control.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
/// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
private void ResizeBottom_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    if (ActualHeight + e.VerticalChange < MinHeight)
        return;

    Height = ActualHeight + e.VerticalChange;

    if (sender != null)
        Container.InvalidateSize();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, `ActualWidth` you need to look for. But window's constructor is not the right place to get it since `window is not rendered yet`. Instead use `Loaded` event -

```
public DatabaseTableWindow(string tableName, DataTable fields, string primaryKey)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.tableName = tableName;
    this.fields = fields;
    this.primaryKey = primaryKey;
    lblTableName.Content = tableName;
    Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);        
}

void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    double x = this.ActualWidth;
}
```

**EDIT**

In place of `Loaded`, try hooking to `ContentRendered` event in your constructor -

```
this.ContentRendered += new EventHandler(MainWindow_ContentRendered);

void MainWindow_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   double x = this.ActualWidth;
}
```

Comment: I've tried doing this, but for some reason the event is not being called. I've copied your code exactly. COuld it be because I'm using the WPF MDI plugin, and the window is contained in an MdiChild?

Comment: I'm guessing this has somethign to do with the library since the window is contained in an MdiChild

Comment: AFAIK you copied the content of tableWindow to the Content of MDIChild. Hence, window's loaded event is not fired ever. Look for any event which you can use to get the Width, constructor is not a right place.

Comment: I've tried the MdiChild loaded event, which fires successfully. However i couldnt get the TableWindow's width from there as it continued returning 0

Comment: Check `ActualWidth`of MDIChild itself since it will be same as that of TableWindow's width since the content is exact same. Isn't it?

Comment: That's my problem unfortunately - the width of the MdiChild is not the same as the TableWindow's width - so im trying to get the TableWindow's width to manually set the MdiChild's width to be the same

Comment: And something worth mentioning is that MdiChild does not have a "SizeToContent" property

Comment: `((Panel)tableWindow.Content).ActualWidth` or `((Panel)tableWindow.Content).Width` - have you tried both of these in loaded event of MDIChild?

Comment: Yes, it's returning the width of the MdiChild window, rather than the contained TableWindow

Comment: Can't you set the width explicitly for your tableWindow?

Comment: My tableWindow is sized to fit the content, but then for some reason its parent MdiChild is rendered with a fixed size of 298, so part of the tableWindow is hidden

Comment: Problem lies somewhere else then which is restricting the size to 298. Manually setting the width might be an option but best would be to find out the code which is restricting the size to 298.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are working with [WPF Multiple Document Interface](http://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/):

If its the MdiChild you need to do the Width-property calculation on then you can bind to the Loaded-Event of the MdiChild-object before you add it to the Container.

```
        var mdiChild = new MdiChild
                           {
                               Title = "Window Using Code",
                               Content = new ExampleControl(),
                               Width = 714,
                               Height = 734,
                               Position = new Point(200, 30)
                           };
    mdiChild.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(mdiChild_Loaded);

        Container.Children.Add(mdiChild);
```

---

```
    void mdiChild_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is MdiChild)
        {
            var width = (sender as MdiChild).Width;
            Debug.WriteLine("Width: {0}", width);
        }
    }
```

Comment: As I've discussed in another answer below, that is not possible because the loaded event is never called. The window is contained in an MdiChild object

Comment: Can you send me a sample project?

Comment: Please have a look at the new answer. Hopefully this helps. I don't know which "MDI-library" you're using.

Comment: Then the answer that is now marked as one is actually not right either.

Comment: The problem is that I require the MdiChild object to be the same size as the window specified in the content part. And for that to happen I need to get the width of the content control, which I cant seem to manage. The plugin im using is infact the one you linked.

Comment: So basically just to emphasise the problem - I've got a window, lets call it MyWindow. Now I've set MyWindow's size to be determined by its dynamically-generated content. Now in my main application I've generated an MdiChild object, whose content is based on MyWindow - i.e. MyWindow's parent is the MdiChild. I would like the MdiChild to have the same size as the MyWindow, as currently the MdiChild is smaller than the MyWindow contained within. So not everything is displayed

Comment: Its out of scope with this question. However, there seems to be bug in this 'plugin' when maximizing the MdiChild and I think that this is what you want (WindowState = WindowState.Maximized). Have a look at this discussion thread: http://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/discussions/81505.

Comment: The plugin is full of bugs, infact I'm trying to look for an alternative

Comment: I think calculating the width and height is also useless in this regard, because maximizing the MdiChild seems to flow into the Container element, so you need to know how that works in order to achieve your goal, meaning it leaves you halve done.

Comment: I suggest finishing this thread answering the question as it is and asking the people involved with WPF MDI-project how to fix your problem.

Comment: I'm not going to bother with the WPF MDI people as the project has been abandoned. I think the best would be to find something else with similar functionality

Comment: or remove the thread, but RV1987 did not answer this question.

Comment: are you bound to a MDI-solution?

Comment: I haven't tried it, although I've heard a lot about it. However I do not need any docking functionality. All I need is support for numerous small windows. The problem with the library I'm using is that it is very restrictive. Although you can create your own window classes, they must be contained within an MdiChild object - which is a control from this library. Thus it provides a lot of limitations

Comment: Maybe use Reflector then to see how the Maximize function is executed?

Answer (score 0):

try snoop the window and go over the tree to see the values

[snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/)